# How to return all data from one column sugar orm

Tags: android, arrays, orm

How to return all data from one column sugar orm ?

Contact.java

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;
import java.util.List;

public class Contact extends SugarRecord{
String name;
String mail;
public Contact() {
}
public Contact(String name, String mail) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mail = mail;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
List<Contact> allContacts = Contact.listAll(Contact.class);

ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, allContacts);
ListView catsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
catsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How can I Load the name column in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the `ArrayAdapter` you can't do that.

Either you need to form a new `ArrayList<String>` as follows and pass it to `ArrayAdapter`.

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
for(Contact contact:allContacts){
    arr.add(contact.getName()); // or arr.add(contact.name); if it's public
}
```

Or you need to define `customAdapter` extending `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: @Artsait did that help you?

Comment: @Artsait my pleasure :)